# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject

Tags: java, gson, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to make the Identity Toolkit work on my Java App Engine on Eclipse. It works fine until I have to choose my account on AccountChooser.com. After it's chosen, I'm getting the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /kalbasidentitytoolkit. Reason:

JsonObject

Caused by:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:185)
    at com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitVerifierManager.parseCertsResponse(GitkitVerifierManager.java:94)
```

What am I missing? The Quick-app using maven works fine.

Comment: I'd say this was a bug in the Identity Toolkit / failure to deal cleanly with a bad response. I'd suggest setting a breakpoint and examining the incoming response. Here's the code: https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/blob/b1387d43e3ffeda4bf6794f5f5a58410b63d829e/src/main/java/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitVerifierManager.java#L94

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the error is caused by the invalid private key. To isolate the root cause, you can grab the latest [Google Identity Toolkit library 1.2.6](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.identitytoolkit%7Cgitkitclient%7C1.2.6%7Cjar) which was just released. In this version the private key is no longer needed for token verification. Let us know if you still see the same error with the v1.2.6 library.

Comment: Now I'm getting another error:

`Problem accessing /kalbasidentitytoolkit. Reason:

    com.google.common.collect.Iterables.tryFind(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;
Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.tryFind(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;
 at com.google.identitytoolkit.JsonTokenHelper$AudienceChecker.check(JsonTokenHelper.java:74)`

Maybe I'm getting the wrong lib? Same error on maven project

Comment: Can you update the guava library in your project to the latest one? Google Identity Toolkit library requires at least v16 of the guava lib:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>16.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Just tried. It was v15, but the error persists.. On both projects.